# how to tell when scroll bar is at bottom of an asp.net multiline text box

Tags: asp.net, textbox, scroll

I am working on an asp.net page and I have a multiline text box that displays some text. I want the user to have to scroll all the way to the bottom before I display a checkbox for them to continue. My question is how can you tell if the scroll bar is at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

By using javascript:

in Internet Explorer:
document.body.scrollLeft
document.body.scrollTop

in Netscape:
window.pageXOffset
window.pageYOffset

Comment: that'll give me the dimensions but what do I compare to so I know it's the bottom?

Comment: from the top of my head:
if (theTextBox.scrollTop == theTextBox.scrollHeight)
{theCheckBox.visible = true;}